# Google adsense display ads even I tell it not to

Tags: javascript, adsense

I use for some years the following which perfectly work until I notice a small "bug" on mobile and tablet :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
google_ad_client = "ca-pub-XXXX"; 
if (window.innerWidth >= 888) { 
google_ad_slot = "23813373"; 
google_ad_width = 728; 
google_ad_height = 90;
}</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js"></script>
```

If you notice, I don't want to display this ad for device width less than 888px. I work well on desktop but on mobile and tablet, Adsense display an 300x150 ad.

Do I miss something or do Google use its code to optimize display on mobile? Do you notice the same problem, bug? How can I not display this 300x150 ad?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that code will make an ad request no matter how condition evaluate.

The solution is [**create** one responsive AdSense unit](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/3543893), and convert its code to "advanced" mode:

```
<style type="text/css">
.adslot_1 { display: inline-block; width: 728px; height: 90px; }
@media (max-width: 887px) { .adslot_1 { display: none; } }
</style>
<ins class="adsbygoogle adslot_1"
  data-ad-client="ca-pub-1234"
  data-ad-slot="5678"></ins>
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<script>(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});</script>
```

I think this snippet is ready-for-use and you can just apply your publisher ID and the unit ID of your **responsive** unit, and I think it should work as you described: "*I don't want to display this ad for device width less than 888px*".

(**EDIT**, to clarify: `display:none` **on** the `ins` tag in responsive ad code will *prevent* the ad request when `display:none` is applied, and it is the only [**officially supported way** of "hiding" an ad unit](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/3543893#hide) in AdSense. Making an ad request and then hiding that ad is a [**violation** of the policies](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1354736).)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the strange thing is that this code worked before... I check the responsive unit but all my codes are in synch mode so I rather try to find a synch solution for this problem !

Comment: Why you _need_ to use synchronous single-size unit? You can create responsive unit very easily, and that unit is much better for implementation. In AdSense ad units are free, I have 367 and still counting! :)

Comment: @henri_1310 That is strange, there is no difference between these two for the viewer, you should definetly try the async code again.